# Pandas Start/End Date Data Transformation

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

was wondering if somebody can help me make the following data transformation.

I have the following data in this format:

```
ID  Value   Start Date  End Date
A   1   1/31/2015   6/30/2015
B   2   3/31/2015   4/30/2015

And would like it to be in this format instead:
Date    ID  Value
1/31/2015   A   1
2/28/2015   A   1
3/31/2015   A   1
4/30/2015   A   1
5/31/2015   A   1
6/30/2015   A   1
3/31/2015   B   2
4/30/2015   B   2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share sample code that you have probably written to solve your problem. Kindly also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You provide too little info, really to be sure of what you want.  But something as simple as re-indexing works, followed by sorting.

```
data.index = data.dates
data.sort(by='ID')
```

Of course, now you still have your date columns in the dataframe, but both of those can be dropped as needed.  It doesn't look like you are doing anything too substantial here, did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but essentially I want to transpose Start_date and End_date into time-series, and fill in the values as they were.  Does that  make more sense?  Thanks